# Abstract hybrid properties in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am modeling an existing database structure in SQLAlchemy and want to do something like the following:

```
class Employee(AbstractConcreteBase, Base):

    @hybrid_property
    def daily_wage(self):
        pass

class HourlyEmployee(Employee):
    __tablename__ = "HourlyEmployee"

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "hourly",
        "concrete": True,
    }

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    hourly_wage = Column(Float, nullable=False)

    @Employee.daily_wage.overrides.getter
    def daily_wage(self):
        return self.hourly_wage * 8


class DailyEmployee(Employee):
    __tablename__ = "DailyEmployee"

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "daily",
        "concrete": True,
    }

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    wage = Column(Float, nullable=False)

    @Employee.daily_wage.overrides.getter
    def daily_wage(self):
        return self.wage
```

Then I would like to query like this:

```
session.query(Employee).filter(Employee.daily_wage < 8.0).all()
```

However, this does not work.